# Duplicate array items using recursion instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
//This function duplicates all array elements(arr) , then add them to newArr 
//and returns newArr  , it works well using for loop , but i want to make a 
//version of this function using recursion instead of for loop

function dubArr(arr){
    newArr=[];
    for(var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
        newArr.push(2*arr[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
}

// This code uses recursion   

function dubArr(arr){
    newArr=[];

    if(arr.length===0){
        return newArr;
    }
    newArr.push(2*arr[0]);
    arr.shift();
    dubArr(arr);
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: do 'return dubArr(arr);'  and pass  newArr and concat

Comment: Your recursive call isn't sharing the new array, and in fact is overwriting it because you've made it an implicit global. So you're only going to be returning the last "version" of `newArr`, which happens on the last call with the `newArr=[]` assignment.

Comment: It's unclear what the current code is doing wrong and why you want it to recurse.

Comment: @TravisPlunk: he wants to create a new array with the items from the original multiplied by 2. He wants to use recursion to understand how it would be done. I'm guessing this is some sort of homework assignment.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: @ squint , you understand me well , thanks. 
Now , what shoud i do ? , where should i write newArr=[]; and return it ??

Answer (score 0):

here is a recursive version of your function :

```
function dubArr(arr, index, newArr){
  if (!newArr)
    newArr = new Array();
  if (index < arr.length) {
   newArr.push(2*arr[index]);
   index++;
   return dubArr(arr, index, newArr);
  }
  return newArr;
}

var tab = [12, 2, 36, 14];
var newTab = dubArr(tab, 0);
console.log(newTab);
```